# Is it ok if there is brine on top of my sauerkraut but not in the middle and bottom portion of my jar while fermenting?

Tags: fermentation, brining, mold, sauerkraut

Not my 1st time making sauerkraut but 1st time this seems to happen to me.

In my 2 biggest jars (4l.) I put small glass containers as weight (fit perfectly) and filled my jars quite a bit... so I know that , that is why my brine is spilling out... but my question is ...will it spoil inside my jar if there is no brine in the middle portion? Or not ferment properly? Or as long as it’s sealed on top with brine and weight, it will be okay?!
Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there’s brine on top, there is definitely brine in the middle and bottom. Gravity sees to that.

It’s likely that during the active fermentation, enough gas has built up in these areas that it looks like no brine is left. If you sharply knock the container against the counter a few times, you’ll see that (some of) the gas is dislodged.

Things are fine. If brine has spilled, once fermentation settles down there may be insufficient brine to cover the top. If this occurs, make up a bit more brine (scale the amount of salt and water in equal proportion) to cover.